# страницы с другими id в одной странице

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, yii2

у меня сейчас есть страница со списками материалов, и когда я нажимаю на этот список ссылка открывается в новом окне (то есть вкладке), тут и вопрос как сделать так чтобы эти страницы загружались снизу списка без перенаправления или открытия страницы

Comment: Копать примерно в эту сторону -> делается на AJAX: получаете id записи, отправляете запрос к БД, а в ответ получаете контент, который показываете под списком страниц. За вас никто ничего делать не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен ajax. И скрипт на сервере, который отдаёт только данные или часть html для отрисовки нужного DOM.

```js
function more(data) {
  return fetch('//httpbin.org/get?data='+encodeURIComponent(data))
    .then(res => res.json());
}

let i = 0;
document.getElementById('more')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
  ++i;
  more(`<b>Динамический</b> контент ${i}`)
    .then(content => {
    let addition = document.createElement('div');
    addition.innerHTML = content.args.data;
    document.getElementById('content')
      .appendChild(addition);
  })
})
```

```html
<div id=content>
  <div>Статический контент</div>
</div>
<button id=more>Ещё...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил использовать pjax виджет yii2. Пример

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

<li><a href='/example'>Ссылка</a></li>
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'content']);
Pjax::end();

<script>
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
        $.pjax({
            url        : $(this).attr('href'),
            container  : '#content',
            timeout    : 10000,
            push : false,
            raplace: false,
            scrollTo : false,
        })
    });
</script>
```

При нажатии на ссылку будет подгружаться содержимое страницы /example в блок с id = content. Более подробно можно посмотреть по ссылке http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html